# Can I use a regex for the delimiter for String.split()?

Tags: javascript

Are there browsers which can only handle strings or single char strings?

Being able to use a regex in this situation is incredibly awesome. It seems to work great on Chrome, too.

Comment: I love how the title asks on question and the content asks a different question which is almost the opposite.

Comment: @epascarello Well... yeah, you're right. You people and your logic... I think what I meant is that if you simply answer the title question with some amount of authority, I'd be satisfied.

Comment: @Hello71 is justified in mentioning I should have googled harder. I did google, but did not end up stumbling over to MDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use either a string or a regular expression as the argument to `.split()`.  See [doc at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) or page 148 in the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) for more info.